# c++ accessing variable from nested class method

Tags: c++, oop

How can I access class attribute from its nested class method?

```
class Class1
{
public:
    int attribute;
    void Method1() { 
        class Class2
        {
            public:
               void Method2() { 
                   //here I need to access attribute from Class1
               }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [struct in class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550711/struct-in-class)

Comment: I would just pass `this` either as a method parameter or when constructing `Class2`.

Comment: @refp: The link you suggested is a bit different.

Comment: Inside `Class2::Method2()`, you would need some global accessor funciton to find Class1's `this` so you could then access its public attribute. Or, you can pass `Class1`'s `this` to `Class2` as part of `Class2`'s construtor so it knows who its parent is so that it can access `Class1`'s public attributes.

Comment: @MM. it boils down to the same thing.

Comment: If you only need 1 attribute, you should pass it in. If you need multiple, pass in `Class1`'s `this`.

Comment: I am using method 2 as a recursive method so I want to avoid any variable passing

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `this` to the inner class. For example:

```
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1() : class2(this) {
    }

    int attribute;
    void Method1() { 
    };

    class Class2
    {
        Class1 *parent;
    public:
        Class2(Class1 *parent) : parent(parent) {
        }
        void Method2() { 
             // parent->attribute
        }
   } class2;
};
```

Comment: It isn't shown nor specified that `Class2` will always be used by `Class1`. Without that specification, there is no need for Class1 to always initialize `Class2` on `Class1`'s construction.

Comment: But the two approaches are quite different things. no?

Comment: Why can not I declare a class with methods inside another method? I did and it works

Comment: It's just a sample to how call parent's method. He can do it with temporary `Class2` object.

Answer (score 2):

Following is one way of doing it with minor changes to OP's code.

```
#include <cassert>

class Class1
{
    public:
        Class1( int attribute ) : attribute_( attribute ) {
        }
        void Method1() { 
            class Class2
            {
                public:
                    Class2( Class1 * parent ) : parent_( parent ) {
                    }
                    int parentAttribute() const { 
                        return parent_->attribute_;
                    }
                private:
                    Class1 * parent_;
            };
            Class2 c2( this );
            assert( c2.parentAttribute() == attribute_ );
        }
    private:
        int attribute_;
};

int main() {
    Class1 c1( 42 );;
    c1.Method1();
}
```

The code is also posted at http://codepad.org/MUF3a8jL

Comment: @MM. Thanks! I never did this before, this is something I learned today :-)