# Several questions regarding separating Interface from implementation

Tags: c++, class, interface, implementation

Ok so I have this header

```
using namespace std;

class students
{
private:
struct record {
    int RUID;
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    vector<double>quiz_grades;
    array<double, 3>exam_grades;
};

vector<record>student_records;

public:

friend void change_name();
void setRUID (int idnt);
void setFirstName (string first);
void setLastName (string last);
void setQuiz (vector<double> quiz);
void setExam (array<double, 3> exam);

};
```

I have to write all the functions of the class in a separate cpp file.

I have tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "students.h"
using namespace std;

void students::setRUID (int idnt)
{
      RUID = idnt;
}
```

but how do I access the struc inside the class students?

If I try this `void students::record::setRUID (int idnt)` it doesn't work since there is no declaration for setRUID inside record.

Question 2. 
I have to 3 random score for quiz and exam for each student. I know how to do that but did I declare the function right?

Question 3. 
Where would I declare the size of vector? 
although there are some error here would this work?

```
void students::setQuiz(vector<double> quiz)
{
  int size = 3;
  quiz_grades.resize(size);
  quiz.resize(size);
  srand(0);
  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
  {
    quiz[i] = rand()%100 + 0;
  }

  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
  {
    quiz_grades[i] = quiz[i];
  }
}
```

or Do I use main to insert random grades for each student?

Basically this is the requirement

"*Write a header file for class definition, a cpp file for the functions of the class, and a main.cpp file.*"

I'm new to this topic, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If yoir class is called "students" and it manages a multitude of students, who is going to be mutated by `setFirstName`? Perhaps yoi want to start with a class reoresenting a single student. I suggest you call it "student". When you nail its interface down, and no earlier, start working on something that keeps information on many students together (if you still need that).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering 1st question.
Structure is like class, they are just the template. Firstly, they need to be *instantiated*. Your struct inside class will look like this.

```
class student {
    struct record {
        int RUID;
    };
// instantiate structure
    record recordInstance;
public:
    void setRUID();
    };
```

by now `RUID` can be access through the class and struct instances.

---

Next step, just modified the `setRUID()` function as:

```
void students::setRUID (int idnt) {
      recordInstance.RUID = idnt;
}
```

---

similar question:
[struct in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550711/struct-in-class)